# Trigger ngf-select programmatically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-file-upload

I have a directive that should open file picker window when a controller variable changes. Here is the snippet of the directive:

```
angular.module('settingsInternal')
    .directive('triggerUpload', function ($timeout) {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element) {
          scope.$watch('mainCtrl.watchedVariable', function (variable) {
            if (variable) {
              $timeout(function () {
                element.triggerHandler('click');
              }, 20);
            }
          });
        }
      };
    });
```

The problem I'm having is that I cant trigger the ngf-select on the div. It works perfectly fine when manually clicking on the div, and the watch function calls element.triggerHandler('click') properly. I have wasted several hours trying to figure out the reason why this doesn't work, if someone had a similar problem please help me figure out where the problem lies.

P.s. Dont pay attention to variable names, they are for demonstrational purposes.

Comment: You could add in another variable to your `ngIf` statement, e.g. instead of `ng-if="myConditional"`, you could put `ng-if="forceOpen || myConditional"`, then from your controller you can toggle `forceOpen`

Comment: not sure what `ngf-select` is. Might try using native click ... `element[0].click()`

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't in angular's ngf-select but in the input[type=file], which the directive uses. Input[type=file] has to be initialized by user made event, so if you want to open file upload window with a function you have to call that function from a user made event.
I hope this helps someone that has experienced a similar problem.